# javafx TabPane setSelection doesn't switch the tab

Tags: kotlin, javafx

I want to control the TabPane and switch tabs with a Canvas, basically hide the tab headers and use canvas instead, the canvas displays different "Devices" and when user click on the device, the TabPane switch to show the content of that device.

```
fun canvasFlow_Click(mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {
    val d = flowPresenter.click(mouseEvent)
    if (d != null) {
        flowPresenter.select(d)
        logger.info("switch to ${d.position}")
        tab.selectionModel.clearSelection()
        tab.selectionModel.select(d.position)
    }
}
```

Why select doesn't work? I don't see tab content changed. from log, I see "switch to 1", "switch to 2" correctly, just the tab doesn't switch! Why?

Comment: [mcve] please ... and stick naming conventions when showing code publicly,  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#function-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: this is plain javafx and might not be the exact solution in your case (hard to tell without example) - but actually I can reproduce the described behavior.

The problem seems to be calling clearSelection: TabPane with tabs should have exactly one selected tab - which is not specified.  <strike>But every internal collaborator (skin, header, listener) goes to great lengths to guarantee that constraint</strike> - this assumption was wrong, in fact the skin gets confused if the selection changes to empty - the previously selected content is not removed. Might be a bug, either don't allow the selectionModel to be empty or improve the skin to cope with it (wondering how that would be supposed to look - hide the content?)

Anyway, here the solution is to not call that method before manually selecting a tab. There's no need to do so anyway, it's a SingleSelectionModel so takes care of allowing at most one item selected.

An example: un/comment the clearSelection and see how the content is not/ correctly updated with/out the call.

```
public class TabPaneSelection extends Application {

    private Parent createContent() {

        TabPane pane = new TabPane();
        HBox headers = new HBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int index = i;
            Tab tab = new Tab("header " + i, new Label("content " + i));
            pane.getTabs().add(tab);
            Button button = new Button(tab.getText());
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                // do __not__ clear selection
                //pane.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                pane.getSelectionModel().select(index);
            });
            headers.getChildren().add(button);
        }

        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(pane);
        content.setTop(headers);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent(), 400, 300));
        //stage.setTitle(FXUtils.fxVersion());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: "_or improve the skin to cope with it (wondering how that would be supposed to look - hide the content?)_" – Given the `SelectionModel` API provides no mechanisms to enforce something is always selected, I think the only reasonable behavior for `TabPane` is to handle this scenario and hide all content if no tab is selected. The other option is for the control (or its skin/behavior) to watch the selection model and select a default tab if the selection is cleared (when the tabs aren't empty, of course). That seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: yes removing "clearSelection" fixed my problem! I need to dig into the clearSelection document to understand this. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped :) But I think that @Slaw is spot-on: the specification of clearSelection doesn't leave much leeway - _clears .. of all selected indices_ and there are tests that the model is empty after the call in TabSelectionModel (and all other concrete impl). Seems to be the skin internals that can't cope with that empty (didn't dig though, what exactly is going wrong: it appears like the skin forgets to set the previously selected content invisible on setting the new selected content visible if the selection had been empty in between)